# How do I update a field in ng-repeat from a function?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to update a subtotal when quantity is changed, within a repeat. The subtotal is not getting updated.
Here is the relevant code in my view:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.cartItems">
    <div class="col-sm-6 cartItemLabel" ng-bind="item.label"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 inputItem">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="item.id" name="item.id" ng-change="updateSub(item)" ng-model="item.qty">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 inputItem">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="item.id" name="item.id" ng-model="item.value">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 inputItem">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="item.id" name="item.id" ng-model="item.subTotal">
    </div>
</div>
```

And, from my controller:

```
self.updateSub = function(item) {
    val = item.value;
    qty = item.qty;
    return item.subTotal = val * qty;
};
```

The data comes from JSON within the controller, for now. I hope to move it to a DB later:

```
self.cartItems = [
        {id: 1, label: "Band-Aids (box)", value: 1.5, qty: 0, subTotal: 0},
        {id: 2, label: "Binders – 1/2”", value: 6.5, qty: 0, subTotal: 0},
        {id: 3, label: "Binders – 1”", value: 6.5, qty: 0, subTotal: 0},
        {id: 4, label: "Binders – 1 1/2”", value: 7.5, qty: 0, subTotal: 0},
        {id: 5, label: "Binders – 2”", value: 8.5, qty: 0, subTotal: 0}
    ]
```

Comment: What's not working ?

Comment: any console errors ?

Comment: @Omri Aharon Sorry. The sub total field is not updating

Comment: it should work, nothing wrong with code

Comment: You have accessed,  self.cartItems from controller as ctrl.cartItems but, you are using self.updateSub directely as updateSub, which doesn't make sense to me, if they are in same controller. Can you have (like) exact js and html code?

Comment: @K.Toress no errors in the console

Comment: Works here - http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/12488/

Comment: it is problem related to `controllerAs` @OmriAharon check my answer

Comment: @pankajparkar Yes looks correct

Comment: @progrrammer That was it! Thanks much. I changed the call to the function to include the contoller. I'll post the answer.

Comment: I didn't post. @pankajparkar beat me to it :-) Thank you all for helping. Amazing community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using `controllerAs` `ng-change` method should be

`ng-change="ctrl.updateSub(item)"` should use `ctrl` alias of controller

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/csiCaHcPiASpiCxo6oPu?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it make more sense to dynamically calculate the total on each line, then evaluate it? That way as the total is altered the binding It will automatically work it out as the user types...

{{ item.qty * item.value }}

Wouldn't it make more sense to dynamically calculate the total on each line? And evaluate it? That way as the total is altered the binding will automatically work it out :) You're not firing the extra event then :)

Comment: I am new to MVC. But, shouldn't logic be kept out of the view?

Comment: I wouldn't make another callback for that especially as the logic is so simple; you're right no it shouldn't. If each line was doing more than one simple calculation I certainly would field this out to its own function but as it stands is use AngularJS to manage the binding. FYI I'm a newbie to AngularJS and I'm finding these kind of posts perfect to answer my own questions :)